# INSERT INTO with SELECT and rand() confusing variables

Tags: mysql, variables

I am trying to make part of my table A copied to table B:

```
@t1 := 1
INSERT INTO B
SELECT x, y, (@t1:=@t1+1)
FROM A
WHERE z=1
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 10
```

What I wanted is to get in table B (third column) the values from 1 to 10, but it is making values like 12, 124, 45 etc... I wonder if it first does the variables and then the order by rand() as the values never exceeds numbers of rows in table A.

Is there any other way I could get 10 random rows from A to B and mark them in third column (sort column) from 1 to 10? In one mysql statement, I know how to do it with 10 inserts ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort first, then calculate row number over the rows returned from the order by/limit:

```
SET @t1 := 1;

INSERT INTO B
SELECT x, y, (@t1:=@t1+1)
FROM (
  SELECT x, y
  FROM A
  WHERE z=1
  ORDER BY rand()
  LIMIT 10) ten_rows
```

Comment: Thanx. I had to made SET @t1:=1 (did you forget the SET?)

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a nested query:

```
INSERT INTO B
    SELECT x, y, (@t1:=@t1+1)
    FROM (
        SELECT x, y
        FROM A
        WHERE z=1
        ORDER BY rand()
        LIMIT 10
    ) A1
    WHERE @t1 := 1
```